# Payment gateway integration issue without any error code How to resolve?

Tags: php, ccavenue

Getting the following error after integrating ccavanue payment gateway.

Something went wrong while processing your request.
Don't worry... It happens to the best of us.

Go back to http://webistename

Merchant Id , Access key and Working key given properly. Request url is same as the Web Store URL in merchant account. Why i am getting this error , what are the possibilities.

I submit the following form

```
<form method="post" id="ccavenu_form" name="ccavenu_form"action="https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="encRequest" value="hashvalue">
                <input type="hidden" name="access_code" value="accescode">
                <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="000000">
                <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="123456">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2000">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="INR">
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="http://webistename/ccavenue/responseurl">
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="http://webistename/ccavenue/cancelurl">
                <input type="hidden" name="language" value="EN">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
```

Comment: I submit the following form

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code, the most likely cause for this error is that the domain associated with the Key you are using is not the one listed for the Key in your account. Either that, or you have a typo somewhere in one of the codes.

Comment: Actually it might just be a problem on the CCAvenue side. There are numerous online complaints with the same error, suggesting that the company is actually processing the request in the background, but still displaying that error.

Comment: More info. Check out their reviews: http://www.mouthshut.com/review/CCAvenue-review-mqopmtsuos